# How manage the online/offline status of the user in SignalR

Tags: javascript, signalr

I have created the chat application with `SignalR version 2.2.1` and I would like to create the information about user status - that means online/offline state.

I have tried use the method:

```
public override Task OnConnected()
{
  var token = Context.QueryString["token"];
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(token)) return Task.FromResult(0);

        using (var dbContext = new AppDbContext())
        {
            dbContext.UserConnections.Add(new UserConnection { ConnectionKey = Context.ConnectionId, UserId = token.GetUserId() });
            dbContext.SaveChanges();
        }

        Clients.Others.UserConnected(token.GetUserId());

        return Task.FromResult(0);
}

public override Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled)
{
    using (var dbContext = new AppDbContext())
        {
            var connection = dbContext.UserConnections.First(x => x.ConnectionKey == Context.ConnectionId);

            var userId = connection.UserId;

            if (connection == null) return Task.FromResult(0);

            dbContext.UserConnections.Remove(connection);
            dbContext.SaveChanges();
        }

        Clients.Others.UserDisconnected(userId);

        return Task.FromResult(0);
}
```

I don't know how correctly work with disconnect method on the client - because when user refresh the browser automaticly is called the `OnDisconnected` event with parameter `stopCalled=true` - I can now send some information about disconnection this user and set the icon for offline but immediately is user connect again and the icon is set to the online state and the user experience is strange.

How can I manage the disconnect state on javascript client without blinking the online/offline status especialy thought refresh page?

Comment: It is not the optimal solution but...postpone...just wait few seconds and if user reconnected then do nothing.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti But where wait a few second? On javascript side? Can you share some code with your idea?

Comment: No, server side. I'm with phone, I'll post later if no one else will answer. Just put the ID of the client in a queue and start a timer that will fire after 5 seconds. When client connects first remove its entry (if any) from that queue (and stops the timer if there aren't other items in the queue) then exit. Do what your're doing now if there is not any entry. Or keep the timer running and mark as disconnected only entries older than 5 seconds (easier). More or less code you would use for a debouncing function.

Comment: OK, can I send the information with disconnected users to the clients which is connected to the hub?

Comment: Just wait those 5 seconds, clients will be notified little bit later. If lag is too much you can even reduce it to 1 or 2 seconds.

Comment: It sounds great, I will be happy if you'll paste the example on server side.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti some update? :)